# Create a Database with name from variable on Databricks (in SQL, not in Spark)

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

How to create a database with a name from a variable (in SQL, not in Spark) ?

I've written this :

```
%sql
SET myVar = CONCAT(getArgument('env'), 'BackOffice');
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS myVar
```

("env" is a dropdown widgets)

But it creates me a database called "myvar".

**EDIT 1 :**

When I use ${myVar}, it shows me this :

[image]

And this :

[image]

Here is the link of "current SQL widgets" : https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html#widgets-in-sql

**EDIT 2 :**

When I type this, it works :

[image]

But not this :

[image]

Comment: Use `${}` to reference a variable in Spark SQL: `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${myVar}`

Comment: Hello, when I use this methode, it show me a blank textbox where I must fill in the variable "myVar". I'll edit my first post to show you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by string interpolating using widgets:

`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${env}_BackOffice`